# Typescript: Functions with properties

Tags: typescript

I recently discovered that you can do this in JS:

```
function foo() {
  console.log("FOO");
}

foo.bar = "FOOBAR";

foo(); // logs "FOO"
console.log(foo.bar); // "FOOBAR"
```

Now my question is: How can I express this kind of object/function in typescript, e.g. when passing it to another function as a parameter?

This obviously throws an error...

```
type Foo = () => void;

function test(foo: Foo) {
  console.log(foo.bar); // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '() => void'.ts(2339)
}
```

Any ideas other than declaring it as an `any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a call signature and `bar` property to `Foo` type:

```
type Foo = {
    () : void;
    bar: string
}

function test(foo: Foo) {
  console.log(foo.bar); 
}
```

Alternatively write it as intersection:

```
type FooFn = () => void;
type Foo2 = FooFn & {bar: string}

function test2(foo: Foo2) {
  console.log(foo.bar); 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nGA7KBeKAKAlGgfFANzgEsATAbgChLRJYE0oBvSqNzHALkJItfYBGAQwBO3AM7ARxJAHNKAX2q1o8OACZGa5FABkzYWKiTpcpZQBmAVyQBjYMTgpgESRgsJuanCza2n4nAANhAAdEFwsu4IoYZY5FCK1NZ2Dk5QLpLq0XBeCOo%20-P5IgSHhkTmxovGJCkA)

Answer (score 1):

You can express that with an `interface` with a call signature:

```typescript
interface FunctionWithBar {
    (): void;     // <=== Makes this callable, in this case accepting no params
                  // and returning nothing
    bar: string;  // Also has a `bar` proprerty of type string
}

function example(f: FunctionWithBar) {
    f();
    console.log(f.bar);
}

function foo() {
    console.log("FOO");
}

foo.bar = "FOOBAR";

example(foo);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcQLMA9iAdWDAAsAhOKZAbwChkHkAKASgC5kA3XYAEwG56jAEaUOAZzBRQAc0EBfWrRiZseEMggAPOAFsADgBsITGBwxYc+IqQpQWNIQxitBjZAnzjcxgHSHcGVNfUXsFJRVLdWQYXFxWR3dPEG8-AKCAIlQAeWyMlnDlOJDKZABeZCzcsgBBACUMwVptPSMTWNwCoA)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to merge function with namespace, a more typescript approach as shown below,

```
function foo() {
  console.log("FOO");
}
namespace  foo {
  export const bar = "FOOBAR";
}

foo(); // logs "FOO"
console.log(foo.bar); // "FOOBAR"

function test(f: typeof foo) {
  console.log(f.bar); // Property 'bar' now exists
}
```

Comment: Why is this a „more typescript“ approach? Never really used namespaces before...

Comment: by that, I mean TS can merge function with namespace, a feature more "unique" to TS.